# How to create a function in CFML within some SQL queries?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I would like to create a function in CFML taking 3 parameters (a number and two dates). The function will then perform a few cfquery queries on these data like SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT...Any idea on how to code this function ? I'm a cfml newbie so be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is very basic and reviewing the documentation of cffunction should be enough to get you started: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html

Answer (score 2):

Adobe docs have a section on how to write UDFs(User Defined Functions).  Probably best to start there:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UDFs_03.html